# What to add in my controller in Grails?

Tags: grails

I'm doing an application where after log in, User gets some settings (in check-boxes) which are Boolean in my database. 
I'm trying to make that every User have his own settings checked, apropose when User logs checked are those fields where the value in the database is 1. My check-box is:

```
<g:checkBox name="task" value="${setting?.message}" />
<label class="text2" for="calendar">Things to done</label>
```

What I have to write in my controller?

Comment: Unable to understand you problem. provide some more detail.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll try to give better explanation: User have privilege to change some settings through check-boxes. When my User logs in I want that he can see what he checked in last log in.

Comment: when user checked or update value, save that value in db in userhistory table ,and next time he logged in your system, than u can show him last checked value from that userhistory table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your scenario i understand there exist a one to many relationship between user and setting, as you explain after user successfully login user is take it to a view where are listed all possible setting.

you can do this in the view

```
<g:each in="${settings}" var="setting">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <g:checkBox name="settings" value="${setting}" checked="${user?.settings?.contains(setting)}"/> ${setting}
    </label>
</g:each>
```

i took this code from a similar scenario i solve someday ago you can see it here [in this github repo](https://github.com/ilmoralito/ds/blob/master/grails-app/views/user/profile.gsp#L40)

after sending the form in the controller you can handle in this way

```
def settings = params.list("settings")
```

you can see the full action controler example [here](https://github.com/ilmoralito/ds/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/ni/edu/uccleon/UserController.groovy#L110)

You could now apply some user.addToSettings or user.removeFromSetting in order to save selected settings

i hope it help you